# Preference based assignment problem to maximize utility

Tags: graphs, optimization, linear-programming, matching, assignment-problem

I am studying an optimization problem which can be recast as an LP I have described below. I wish to understand the structure of optimizers of the original problem by studying the optimizers of the LP. There are several versions of assignment problems that are comparable to our LP, such as the many-to-many and many-to-one assignment problems, but I haven't been able to identify any assignment problem that specifically address all our constraints. I would appreciate any help in directing me to problems that solve LP of this form because I haven't been able to find any in the literature.

Let $X=\{1,2,\cdots,q\}$ be a non-empty set of symbols of size $q$ and let $\mathcal{U}:X\times X \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ denote a utility/reward function. Let $\mu:X \times X \longrightarrow [0,1]$ be a function where $0\leq \mu(x',x)\leq 1, \forall x,x' \in X$ and $\sum \limits_{x'\in X}\mu(x',x)=1, \forall x \in X.$ We want to identify optimal $\mu^*$ for the following problem:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
(P):\max_{\mu} \quad & \sum \limits_{x,x' \in X}\mu(x',x)\mathcal{U}(x',x),\\
\textrm{s.t.} \quad & \sum \limits_{x' \in X} \mu(x',x)=1, \forall x \in X \\
\quad & \mu(x',x')\geq \mu(x',x),\forall x,x'\in X\\
\quad & \mu(x',x)\geq 0,\forall x,x'\in X.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Does the above LP ($P$) characterize some known standard problem in literature? Although this problem can be seen as some form of assignment problem or a matching problem, but the requirement in second constraint, i.e., $\mu(x',x')\geq \mu(x',x), \forall x,x' \in X$ is not seen in the most popular versions of assignment or matching problems. Consequently, some portion of $x$ can be assigned to $x'$ if some portion of $x'$ is assigned to $x'$ and $x$ can be assigned at the most $\mu(x',x')$ portion of $x'$. This constraint also implies the possibility of an optimal $\mu^*$  where $\mu^*(x,x)=0$ for some $x \in X$. This suggests that we could encounter a case where under an optimal policy, there could exist a $x$ which receives no assignment. Please let me know if this problem is a characterization of some well known standard problem?